# How do I use the replace function in arcpy?

Tags: python, replace, arcpy

I am trying to use an update cursor to replace abbreviations in a field (eg: ST to STREET, AVE to AVENUE etc) but cant seem to get this to work. I have tried every permutation but am obviously missing something. The code runs but makes no changes to the field. Any suggestions?
Many thanks

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:/data"

fc = "blah.shp"

cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["BLAH_BLAH"])

for row in cursor:
    row = row.replace("ST", "STREET")
    cursor.updateRow(row)

del row
del cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

row is a list of fields, you cannot access field values directly with it. Use the field's index instead: `row[0] = row[0].replace("ST", "STREET")`

Comment: Thank you. I figured that out but what happens is that every instance of the key changes (eg: Bathurst St becomes Bathurstreet Street etc). I have tried splitting the row and finding only those rows which end with ST or AVE etc but am having difficulty indicating that only the last section in the string should be replaced [-1] but  it is not working. I think my code is off. I do not have my code with me but will post it later. Thanks for your help by the way. It is appreciated.

Comment: Add a space to the string you want to replace: .replace(" ST", " STREET"). I don't know what particular cases you encounter in your data but this can help for some at least.

Comment: I managed to figure it out and fixed my problem but thought I would post my result anyway. Thanks for your help! import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:/Data"


fc = "BLAH.shp"


cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["ST_NAME"])

for row in cursor:
    addrlist = row[0].rsplit()
        
    if 'ST' in addrlist[-1]:
        addrlist = row[0].rsplit()
        addrlist.pop(-1)
        addrlist.append('STREET')
        row[0] = ' '.join(addrlist)

Answer (score 1):

table = r'C:\DATA'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, "ST_NAME") as cursor:

```
    for row in cursor:
        if "ST" in row[0]:
           row[0] = row[0].replace("ST", "STREET")
        if "AVE" in row[0]:
            row[0]= row[0].replace("AVE", "AVENUE")
        if "RD" in row[0]:
            row[0]= row[0].replace("RD", "ROAD")
        if "DR" in row[0]:
            row[0]= row[0].replace("DR", "DRIVE")
        if "BLVD" in row[0]:
            row[0]= row[0].replace("BLVD", "BOULEVARD")
        if "PK" in row[0]:
            row[0]= row[0].replace("PK", "PARK")
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```